# How to get param in url like /api/groups?sdk&type=1 with java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, restful-url

For example, URL can be:

```
/api/groups?sdk&type=1
```

or

```
/api/groups?app&type=1
```

In java, I want to know the param in the url is sdk or app.
I have tried something like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseResult testGet(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String sdk, @RequestParam int type) {

   ...
}
```

Comment: use @PathVariable

Comment: Why don't you set it as another query param? So it could be like: `/api/groups?param=app`

Comment: Could you give an example?@shantaram_t

Comment: Can I ask what are you trying to achieve? Are you wanting one request handler method to process both of these? Or are you wanting to have a method for each parameter? This would define your implementation.

Comment: I want to know the param in whether the url is sdk or app, and I  want to have a method for each parameter@MartinByers

Comment: Do you like url as `/api/groups/app?&type=1` or `/api/groups/sdk?&type=1` , `sdk` and `app` before `?`

Comment: I hope I can put them after '?', but I have to put them after the question mark for some reasons. So I don't know how to deal with it.@shantaram_t

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can have 2 methods and use the `params` variable in the `@RequestMapping` anotation to discriminate between the methods.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="sdk")
public ResponseResult getSdk(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam int type) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="app")
public ResponseResult getApp(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam int type) {
    ...
}
```

You may or may not need to add the `value = "/groups"` to your request mapping, depending on how you have configured your class/app.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a parameter for `app` and `sdk` so your url will be `/api/groups?param=sdk&type=1` or `/api/groups?param=app&type=1`. you can find sample code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RestResponse testGet(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) String param, @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type) {

}
```